# Login to outlook fails from AWS Lambda when using IMAPLIB

Tags: aws-lambda, imaplib

I've been trying to login and fetch email details from outlook using the python imaplib library. While login and email message fetch works for me locally , this fails when I execute this inside an AWS Lambda function.

This was the error message received.

'SELECT command error: BAD [b'User is authenticated but not connected.']'

Username and PW is correct. I am not exactly sure what is going wrong here. :(

Code:

```
IMAP_SERVER = 'outlook.office365.com' 
EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'username@outlook.com' 
EMAIL_PASSWORD = '******' 
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER) 
mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_PASSWORD) 
mail.select()
```

Comment: There are a ton of results when searching this.  Have you tried any of those?

Comment: Did you check your error returns?  Furthermore, almost all free email services include proprietary security protocols, and due to the fact that a lot of abuse comes from cloud servers, those are generally restricted from using them.  Generally they consider IMAP something to be used by an end user in an email client, and by definition anything running in a cloud server is not an end user.